# How to increase the number of MDB instances listening to a JMS Queue in Jboss 4

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, xdoclet

For example, as we configure the number of MDB instances listening to a JMS Queue in ejb 3 as given below,

@ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "someNumber")

I want to know how it can be done in EJB 2.1 Jboss 4.

Currently i use xDoclet for generating the ejb-jar.xml for the MDB and my current declaration is as follows.

```
 * <!-- begin-xdoclet-definition -->
 * @ejb.bean name="myEjb"
 *     acknowledge-mode="Auto-acknowledge"
 *     destination-type="javax.jms.Queue"
 * what to use for max Session??
```

this results in activation configs in ejb-jar.xml as follows

```
 <activation-config>
           <activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
             <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
           </activation-config-property>
           <activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
             <activation-config-property-value>Auto-acknowledge</activation-config-property-value>
           </activation-config-property>
         </activation-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you have should work fine.  If that is not working, I would suspect that you have a deployment descriptor file in your META-INF directory that is over riding the `maxSession` value.

Or, conversely, if the `maxSession` annotation is not being honored, you may have to use a deployment descriptor file, such as an `ejb-jar.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. currently i use xDoclet for generating the  ejb-jar.xml for MDB as upated in the question.

Comment: And what happens if you put maxSession as an activation-config-property in the ejb-jar.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

According to [xdoclet doc](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/tags/ejb-tags.html#@ejb_activation-config-property__0____):

```
* @ejb.activation-config-property
*     name="maxSession"
*     value="someNumber"
```

Comment: Hi areus, thanks for the response.    this is what results in when i do so.        <activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property-name>maxSession</activation-config-property-name>
             <activation-config-property-value><![CDATA[10]]></activation-config-property-value>
           </activation-config-property>

Comment: do you have any idea why "10" gets converted to <![CDATA[10]]>

Comment: Seems like a bug/feature. Are you using last xdoclet version? 1.2.3 I think it was.